# Segmentation Fault During push {lr}

Tags: c, assembly, arm

**Context**

This is from an assignment. I am asking for solution to `Segmentation Fault`, and I am not asking for a solution for the assignment. The problem for me to solve was to implement a recursive function to

[image]

And call the function in c.

When I tested with only assembly with ex) `mov r0, #15`, it worked as expected. Now the problem rose when I tried to call the function from a c file; I got a segmentation fault error.

I do not know why this happened and how to solve. Could not find any solution anywhere. So I am here.

**Symptoms**

`Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0x00008f24 in ?? ()` at `push {lr}` of `add` function. When it is called for the first time.

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int add(int);

int main()
{
    int s = add(15);
    printf("Evaluated: %d",s );
    return 0;
}
```

**assembly.s**

```
.global add


add:
    /*
        args
        r0 [int] - n
        r1 [int] - a_(n-1)
        r2 [int] - a_(n-2)
    returns
        r2 [int] - Summed value, 1 if n = 1 or n = 0
    */
    push {lr}

    cmp r0, #0
    beq if_zero
    cmp r0, #1
    beq if_one
    b else
    
if_zero:
    mov r1, #1

    pop {lr}
    bx lr   

if_one:
    mov r2, #1
    sub r0, r0, #1
    bl add

    pop {lr}
    bx lr   

else:
    sub r0, r0, #1
    bl add

    mov r4, r2
    add r2, r1, r2
    mov r1, r4

    pop {lr}
    bx lr
```

Architecture : ARM

compiled using: `gcc assembly.s main.c -g -marm -o out`

Comment: Sounds like the stack is not set up or stack pointer is not properly initialized, but how can we tell without seeing `main` or the rest of the runtime environment?  In another environment, this function (or at least its first instruction) might work fine.

Comment: @ErikEidt I have given you the `main` in `main.c`. What kind of information do you need more? I am running this in Cyclone-SoC5. On a custom linux OS.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I guess I wanted to see the disassembly for `main`. or maybe for `out`.  Since it is going wrong on the first instruction of `add`, and this first instruction appears reasonable, it appears as it must be an environmental issue.

Comment: It is possible that you have a Stack Overflow due to unbounded recursion.

Comment: @fuz This happens at the very first call of function `add` from `main.c`

Comment: @ErikEidt I am new to assembly. Do you know any specific places I can look for?

Comment: as stated above this indicates that the stack pointer is not setup, it is not pointing at memory your program has access to so the first time you call a function.

Comment: start debug by having the first instruction after add: be a bx lr, simply return, do nothing else in the function.  does that fail.   next have three instructions after add push {lr} pop{lr} bx lr, does that fail?  then try push {r4,lr}. pop {r4,lr} bx lr.   if you cant get through these then you are not going to make it much further...

Comment: if mov r0,#15, bx lr worked and you got a printf to work after then it is not the stack.  because the printf ideally would have triggered it with all the nesting and stack usage it does...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed liked it was a problem of environment.

Compiling using the following command solved my problem. I forgot the `-marm` option.

`gcc assembly.s main.c -g -marm -o out`

Comment: This could be it.  In this case, it is possible that your code was somehow assembled into thumb code but executed as ARM code.